# Can not find file in android.bp

Tags: android, makefile, android-source, android-soong

i build a so file in Android.bp,i use the "include_dirs" to find the ".h" file,but it can not find,here is my code

codeA named A.bp

```
cc_library_static {name :"liba" , static_libs:['libb']}
```

codeB name B.bp

```
cc_library_static {name :"libb",include_dirs:['vendor/dirb']}
```

there is a file named "b.h" in the dir "vendor/dirb"

when i build liba,it got error with "can not find b.h",how to solve it? thank you

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `export_include_dirs` in `B.bp`. But be sure to specify a path relative to `B.bp` there.

`include_dirs` is meant to add additional include directories that are not provided by dependent modules.

Note: `cc_library_static` will create a static library (`.a` file). Use `cc_library_shared` instead if you want to have a shared library (`.so` file).

Comment: hello ,thank you for your advise,but i build "libb",it can build a "libb.a" file, this problem comes when i build "liba"

Comment: i changed the "include_dirs" to "export_include_dirs" ,and i solve this problem ,thank you